# issue with htaccess not setting header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For some reason this new host isn't setting htaccess headers, I use 1and1. previously on 000webhost it worked fine.

Is there maybe a difference in apache versions?

This is my htaccess

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' //ajax.googleapis.com"
```

Comment: Which version of apache are you using?

[2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) | [2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

Comment: I'm not able to check the version. It looks like the syntax is the same for "Header set" in both versions, though.

Comment: Try putting gibberish in htaccess. If you don't get a 500, it's not being read -- either because AllowOverride is off or you aren't hitting the path you think.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file only works if it's behind the directory that I use for my website.

e.g.

`htdocs/.htaccess
htdocs/folder1/index.php`

will now correctly set HTTP headers on 1and1.